# iPhone UIImageView setting UIImages

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm making a Card game and trying to call UIImages from an object's instance variable to update a UIImageView

I have a Deck object, which has an NSArray instance variable of Card objects.

Each Card object has a few instance variables, one of which is an UIImage that I'm trying to display in a UIImageView....and this is where I'm having a problem

The storyboard isn't displaying the UIImageView and i'm not getting any compile errors

The UIImageView that I'm trying to update is cardDisplay (ViewController.h)

Here's some snippets from my code

ViewController.h

```
#import "Deck.h"
#import "Card.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *cardDisplay;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *cardDisplay;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    #import "Deck.h"
    #import "Card.h"

    @implementation ViewController


@synthesize cardDisplay;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Deck *deck = [[Deck alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"%@", deck);

    for (id cards in deck.cards) {
         NSLog(@"%@", cards);
    }

    self.cardDisplay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
         [[deck.cards objectAtIndex:0 ] cardImage]];
}


@end
```

Card.h

```
@interface Card : NSObject
{
    NSString *valueAsString, *suitAsString;
    NSInteger faceValue, countValue;
    Suit suit;
    UIImage *cardImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *valueAsString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *suitAsString;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger faceValue;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger countValue;
@property (nonatomic) Suit suit;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *cardImage;

- (id) initWithFaceValue:(NSInteger)aFaceValue countValue:(NSInteger)aCountValue
                suit:(Suit)aSuit cardImage:(UIImage*)aCardImage;

@end
```

Deck.h

```
#import "Card.h"

@interface Deck : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *cards;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *cards;

@end
```

Deck.m

```
#import "Deck.h"
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Deck

@synthesize cards;

- (id) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSInteger aCount, picNum = 0;

        for(int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
        {
            for(int face = 1; face < 14; face++, picNum++)
            {

                if (face > 1 && face < 7) 
                    aCount = 1;
                else if (face > 6 && face < 10)
                    aCount = 0;
                else
                    aCount = -1;

                NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
                NSString *imagePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/cards/card_%d.png",picNum]];

                UIImage *output = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];

                Card *card = [[Card alloc] initWithFaceValue:(NSInteger)face
                                                countValue:(NSInteger)aCount
                                                suit:(Suit)suit
                                                cardImage:(UIImage *)output];

                [cards addObject:card];
            }

        }
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Comment: did you add the image view in storyboard and connected the outlets ?

Comment: If you have your UIImageview in IBoutlet just link them to file owner.In your  code you have initialized in view did load that is not needed.

Comment: eventually I'm going to setup a timer and display different cards randomly so I was trying to do this strictly by code and not connecting a specific picture to the UIIMageView through the IB.  Is this not updating because I need a delegate to talk to the view from the Deck/Card models

Comment: Well, if you want to do it all in code, you're doing it the wrong way. The image view in your app is the one set up in IB, but the one you set the image on is a new one you alloc init'ed, but never add to your view.

Comment: If you want to add UIIImageView in code just remove IBOutlet `@property (nonautomic,strong) UIImageview  *name;`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
self.cardDisplay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
         [[deck.cards objectAtIndex:0 ] cardImage]];
```

should be:

```
self.cardDisplay.image = [[deck.cards objectAtIndex:0 ] cardImage];
```

You need to set the image on the image view you created in IB, not create a new one. Doing it this way doesn't keep you from doing what you want with the timer later.

Comment: @blitzeus Try logging self.cardDisplay and [[deck.cards objectAtIndex:0 ] cardImage] and see what each gives you.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.cardDisplay); gives the error <UIImageView: 0x71793a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7178bd0>>

Comment: and NSLog(@"%@", [[deck.cards objectAtIndex:0 ] cardImage]); is null

Comment: i'm still stumped why i can't display an image without using the IB

Comment: @blitzeus, you can display an image without using IB -- you can create a UIImageView in code, give it an appropriate frame, and add it to you view as a subview. The way you did it in code, you never added it as a subview of your view. But, you obviously have other problems since the log of  [[deck.cards objectAtIndex:0 ] cardImage] was null.